# How to login into a youtube account on iPhone

Tags: ios, authentication, youtube-api

I want to implement Youtube login authentication in my application. Is there any api that allows this, that I can implement? If so, where could I find it and how would I go about implementing it? I searched a lot but haven't found any solution. If possible, please provide code also.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Objective-C Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).
[Here are few samples](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample).

In iOS you need to do the OAuth2 using WebView.
[Here's a great explanation talk](http://youtu.be/Bp3i71jaWNo?t=16m15s).